# Scan a folder having multiple images to find the darker images

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I have a folder having bunch of images, out of which few images are almost dark like this: [Dark Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJLmi.jpg), and few images are good images like this: [Good images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BV8Ne.jpg)

Basically i am able to identify the darker images by using the below code, for the darker images the np.mean(image) comes below 0.1, and for good images it comes above 0.1 range:

```
from skimage import io, img_as_float
import numpy as np

image = io.imread('C:/Data/Testing/Image_0_5.jpg')
image = img_as_float(image)
print(np.mean(image))
```

But what i want is to pass the specific folder having all the images so that my code can parse through all the images, and list down the images having dark images. Need help on this.

Comment: By "pass the specific folder", do you mean as a command-line argument to your script? You can read command-line arguments out of `sys.argv`. And you can then get the contents of a directory with `os.scandir`, or `os.walk` if you want to also scan subdirectories recursively. Is that all you're looking for?

Comment: @abarnert I meant, to parse the directory to find all the images and apply np.mean(image) on all the images, and save those images whose np.mean value is less than 0.1 in some list or a dataframe.

Comment: So is what I gave you what  you're looking for, or is there still something you don't know how to do? If so, what part are you stuck on?

Comment: @KlausD. Possibly, but I think it's better to assume people want actual help rather than gimme-codes help that will just leave them stuck as soon as they hit the first bug or need to expand it. After all, when I'm wrong in that assumption, they just go away and never reply, so I don't lose anything.

Comment: @KlausD. I don't want anyone to write codes for me, i wanted a direction..

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the direction guys, appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import os
def load_images(folder):
    images = []
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        img = mpimg.imread(os.path.join(folder, filename))
        img = img_as_float(img)
        #print(np.mean(img))
        if img is not None:
            images.append(img)
        if(np.mean(img) < 0.1):
            print filename

load_images('C:/Data/Testing')
```

I have achieved what i was looking for :)