# Traverse through all the images from a directory and sub directories to perform mean intensity of individual images

Tags: python

Below code works fine if the images are in a single directory.

```
from skimage import io, img_as_float
    import matplotlib.image as mpimg
    import os
    import pandas as pd    

def load_images(folder):
    images = []
    data = []
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        img = mpimg.imread(os.path.join(folder, filename))
        img = img_as_float(img)
        if img is not None:
            images.append(img)
        if(np.mean(img) < 0.1):
            print filename
            data.append((folder, filename))
            df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Folder', 'File'])
    return df

df = load_images('C:/Data/Testing')
df.to_csv('final.csv')
```

If my 'C:/Data/Testing' folder has many sub folders and sub folders have the image files, how to deal with it?

Comment: You seem to have ignored the comments on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49643631/scan-a-folder-having-multiple-images-to-find-the-darker-images) that explained that you can use `os.scandir` for a single directory or `os.walk` to recursively scan all of its subdirectories. That comment is still true an hour later, and it tells you exactly what you're asking how to do now.

Comment: @abarnert Ohh might have skipped it, let me try doing what you recommended..

Answer (score 2):

In case if someone is viewing this question, here's the answer to it:

```
from skimage import io, img_as_float
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import os
import pandas as pd

def load_images(n):
    images = []
    data = []
    for dirs in n:
        for filename in os.listdir(dirs):
            img = mpimg.imread(os.path.join(dirs, filename))
            img = img_as_float(img)
            if img is not None:
                images.append(img)
            if(np.mean(img) < 0.1):
                print filename
                data.append((dirs, filename))
                df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Folder', 'File'])
    return df

from glob import glob
folder = glob("C:/Data/Testing/*/")
df = load_images(folder)
```

I hope this helps.